# Where to close a file handle opened at the beginning of a PHP script?

Tags: php, fopen, file-handling, filehandle, fclose

I have a PHP file in which, on the top I create a file handle using `fopen()`. Then then file has a couple of classes, in the functions of which I write stuff to this text file. And ultimately, in the end, i.e. when I am done writing stuff to this file, I have to close this file handle using `fclose()`.

The flow of control is such that, in the following pseudo-code, the function `a_b()` of class `A` is called LAST OF ALL in this PHP script. So, naturally, in the end of the body of `a_b()`, I decided to write **`fclose($fileHandle);`**.

BUT I got an ERROR: **Notice: Undefined variable: fileHandle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tests\Test.php on line 15**

The question is why? Where should I write the statement `fclose($fileHandle)`? Should I write it at the very end of the file?

```
<?php 

$fileHandle = fopen($pathToFileHandle, "a");

class A {
  function a_a() {
    ...
    fwrite($fileHandle, "blahBlahBlah");
  }

  function a_b() {
    ...
    fwrite($fileHandle, "Whatever");
    ...
    fclose($fileHandle);
  }
}

class L {
  function l_a() {
    ...
    fwrite($fileHandle, "Some text");
    ...
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: why not open and close inside method? Is there reason not to do so?

Comment: What @RajeshPaudel said. Also, which one is _line 15_?

Comment: @DimitrisDamilos  `fclose($fileHandle);` - That one is line 15

Comment: @RajeshPaudel No there is no particular reason, but the answer to this will let me understand control-flow better =)

Comment: What type of variable is `$fileHandle` inside the class? Is it coming as public so all functions have access to it?

Comment: @sile inside the methods shouldn't the file handle should be used like this fwrite($this -> filehandle,"    ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having inline code (i.e. code which does something rather code which defines something to be invoked later) mixed up in the same file, [is considered a bad thing](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) - not least because it gives rise to the kind of problem you describe here.

You don't need to explicitly close a file handle - PHP will do this automatically when the script exits.

If you want to do more than just close the file, an alternative to explicitly invoking the close in your thread of execution is to ask PHP to [call a function when the script finishes executing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) (note that a callback can also be an object - i.e. with associated data).

As Renee points out, your issue arises from scope. However its also bad design to split the file operations across two different classes and the procedural side effect. Use a single class to define all the file operations (open, close, read, write). Then pass a reference to that class to other classes which will supply or require data to/from the file.

Answer (score 1):

> Undefined variable: fileHandle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tests\Test.php on line 15

PHP functions cannot access global variables by default. So:

```
$value = 'hello world';
class A {
    public function b () {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

…does not work—`$value` is unavailable in the function.

Use the [`global`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword to make global variables available inside a function:

```
$value = 'hello world';
class A {
    public function b () {
        global $value;
        return $value;
    }
}
```

But, as commenters suggested, if possible it is better to keep the `$fileHandle` variable in the class that uses it and to close the handle as soon as possible.